# Node-Red: Create server and share input

Tags: node.js, sockets, node-red

I'm trying to create a new node for Node-Red. Basically it is a udp listening socket that shall be established via a config node and which shall pass all incoming messages to dedicated nodes for processing.
This is the basic what I have:

```
function udpServer(n) {
    RED.nodes.createNode(this, n);
    this.addr = n.host;
    this.port = n.port;

    var node = this;

    var socket = dgram.createSocket('udp4');

    socket.on('listening', function () {
        var address = socket.address();
        logInfo('UDP Server listening on ' + address.address + ":" + address.port);
    });

    socket.on('message', function (message, remote) {
        var bb = new ByteBuffer.fromBinary(message,1,0);
        var CoEdata = decodeCoE(bb);
        if (CoEdata.type == 'digital') { //handle digital output
            // pass to digital handling node
        }
        else if (CoEdata.type == 'analogue'){ //handle analogue output
            // pass to analogue handling node
        }
    });     

    socket.on("error", function (err) {
        logError("Socket error: " + err);
        socket.close();         
    });

    socket.bind({
        address: node.addr,
        port: node.port,
        exclusive: true
    });

    node.on("close", function(done) {
        socket.close();
    });
}
RED.nodes.registerType("myServernode", udpServer);
```

For the processing node:

```
function ProcessAnalog(n) {
    RED.nodes.createNode(this, n);
    var node = this;
    this.serverConfig = RED.nodes.getNode(this.server);

    this.channel = n.channel;

    // how do I get the server's message here?

}
RED.nodes.registerType("process-analogue-in", ProcessAnalog);
```

I can't figure out how to pass the messages that the socket receives to a variable number of processing nodes, i.e. multiple processing nodes shall share on server instance.

==== EDIT for more clarity =====

I want to develop a new set of nodes:

*One Server Node:*

- Uses a [config-node](http://nodered.org/docs/creating-nodes/config-nodes) to create an UDP listening socket
- Managing the socket connection (close events, error etc)
- Receives data packages with one to many channels of different data

*One to many processing nodes*

- The processing nodes shall share the same connection that the Server Node has established
- The processing nodes shall handle the messages that the server is emitting
- Possibly the Node-Red flow would use as many processing Nodes as there are channels in the server's data package

To quote the Node-Red documentation on config-nodes:

> A common use of config nodes is to represent a shared connection to a
>   remote system. In that instance, the config node may also be
>   responsible for **creating the connection and making it available** to the
>   nodes that use the config node. In such cases, the config node should
>   also handle the close event to disconnect when the node is stopped.

As far as I understood this, I make the connection available via  `this.serverConfig = RED.nodes.getNode(this.server);` but I cannot figure out how to pass data, which is received by this connection, to the node that is using this connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A node has no knowledge of what nodes it is connected to downstream.

The best you can do from the first node is to have 2 outputs and to send digital to one and analogue to the other.

You would do this by passing an array to the `node.send()` function.

E.g.

```
//this sends output to just the first output
node.sent([msg,null]);

//this sends output to just the second output
node.send([null,msg]);
```

Nodes that have receive messagess need to add a listener for `input`

e.g.

```
node.on('input', function(msg) {
   ...
});
```

All of this is well documented on the Node-RED [page](http://nodered.org/docs/creating-nodes/)

The other option is if the `udpServer` node is a **config** node then you need to implement your own listeners, best bet is to look something like the MQTT nodes in core for examples of pooling connections

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. I guess I have not been precise enough on my initial question, as I want to achieve something different. I have edit my initial question for more clarity (I hope)

Comment: So that fits the second option I described, you should look at the MQTT nodes in the core nodes https://github.com/node-red/node-red/blob/master/nodes/core/io/10-mqtt.js